# How to highlight a selected row of a table in Taipy?

Tags: python, taipy

I am working with Taipy GUI to create a web app. So far I am able to generate a table and keep track of a selected row of the table. However, I want to show the user which row they selected by highlighting it on the frontend. I couldn't find how to do this in the docs. Can someone help me?

I checked the docs but didn't find anything that helped me.

Comment: Hey Sai, Feel free to join our Discord Server discord.com/invite/SNNsCDj9? and connect with like-minded individuals and collaborate on your web application buildings :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [*selected* property](https://docs.taipy.io/en/latest/manuals/gui/viselements/table/#p-selected) to get a visual feedback on your selection.

See below a simple example:

```py
from taipy.gui import Gui 

data = {"Name":["A","B","C"], "Age":[1,2,3]}

selected = []

page = "<|{data}|table|on_action=on_selection|selected={selected}|>"

    
def on_selection(state, var_name, action, payload):
    idx = payload['index']
    state.selected = [int(idx)]
    ...


Gui(page).run()
```

[image]